# Solve for $\varphi_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, probability-distributions

$$\varphi_{n+1}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_0(x-a)dx$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(a)=e^{-|a|}$$

Solve for  $\varphi_0:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

This is not a homework. What I have tried might be terribly wrong and misleading.

---

Thank you Yves, following your Fourier transformation I could immediately get:

$$\varphi_0=\delta(x)$$

Well, then further problems arise as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(x)=e^{-|x|}$ is only one of the possibilities.

For example, take $\varphi_0=\delta(x)=\lim_{b\to\infty}e^{-x^2/2^b}$, then $\varphi_\infty(x)$ become the form of  $e^{-x^2}$

---

Strictly in Math, Dirac delta is an operator rather than a function.

Not every $\delta[f(x)]$ works here.

Could you please guide me through the complexity?

Comment: Then what is it; how did you get to this problem?  Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: Many of the problems are randoms ones I found on math competitions, qualifying exams, etc.

Comment: I think the answer is $\varphi_0(x)=\delta(x-a)$, but not sure about the correctness of the reasoning.

Comment: I don't think that a is a parameter. Is it?

Comment: Taking the Fourier transform, $\Phi_{n+1}=\Phi_n\Phi_0$ if I am right, then  $\Phi_{n}=\Phi_0^{n+1}$ ?!

Comment: @RafaBudría. If $\varphi_0(x) = \delta(x-a)$ then we would have $\varphi_n(x) = (\underbrace{\varphi_0 * \cdots * \varphi_0}_{n+1})(x) = \delta(x-(n+1)a)$, so that's not the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think there is any solution. Assuming all $\varphi_n$ are even (since the limit is even), we have $\varphi_{n+1} = \varphi_n * \varphi_0,$ the convolution of $\varphi_n$ and $\varphi_0.$ Taking limits of both sides give $\varphi = \varphi * \varphi_0,$ where $\varphi(a) = e^{-|a|}.$ This requires $\varphi_0 = \delta$ (easier seen taking the Fourier tranform), but that wouldn't make $\lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_n = \varphi.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the anzatz $\varphi_0(x)=ae^{\alpha |x|}$:

Then:
$$
\varphi_{1}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi_{0}(y) \varphi_{0}(y-x)dy\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ae^{\alpha |y|} ae^{\alpha |y-x|}dy\\
$$
If $x\ge 0$:
$$
\varphi_{1}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} a^2e^{\alpha (2y+x)} dy+\int_0^x a^2e^{\alpha (y-y+x)} dy+\int_{x}^{\infty} a^2e^{\alpha (2y-x)} dy\\
= \left. \frac {a^2}{2\alpha}e^{\alpha (2y+x)} \right|_{0}^{\infty}
+ \left. a^2 e^{\alpha x}y    \right|_0^x
+ \left. \frac {a^2}{2\alpha}e^{\alpha (2y-x)} \right|_{x}^{\infty}
$$
All limits exist and vanish only for $\alpha=-|\alpha|<0$, then:
$$
= \frac {a^2}{2|\alpha|}e^{-|\alpha| x} 
+  {a^2}x e^{-|\alpha| x} 
+ \frac {a^2}{2|\alpha|}e^{-|\alpha| x} \\
\varphi_{1}(x)= {a^2}x e^{-|\alpha| x}  +\frac {a^2}{|\alpha|}e^{-|\alpha| x} \\
$$
If $x\le 0$, the integrals are the same than for $|x|$, so:
$$
\varphi_{1}(x)= {a^2}|x| e^{-|\alpha| |x|}  +\frac {a^2}{|\alpha|}e^{-|\alpha| |x|} \\
$$
For the anzatz be able to converge:
$$
\frac{a^2}{|\alpha|}=a \to a=|\alpha|>0
$$
and:
$$
\varphi_{1}(x)= {a^2}|x| e^{-a |x|}  +ae^{-a |x|} \\
$$
The first term vanishes in the next iterations, as you can realize (under work...!).